# Independence of asymptotic joint distribution of order statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, order-statistics, extreme-value-theorem

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n\sim f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a pdf and even function, i.e. $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Now given that $$a_n(X_{(n:n)}-b_n)\xrightarrow{dist.} G_1$$
Then obviously from symmetry we can conclude that $$a_n(-X_{(n:1)}-b_n)\xrightarrow{dist.} G_2$$

where $G_1, G_2$ are standard Gumbel distribution.

Now I have to show,

$$a_n(X_{(n:n)}-b_n,-X_{(n:1)}-b_n)\xrightarrow{dist.} (G_1,G_2)$$

Where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are independent. But I do not know how proceed. Any kind of help appreciable.

There is some general result on it due to Gumbel [Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177731026). If anyone explain this proof simply that also appreciable.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You cannot possibly prove convergence to $(G_1,G_2)$ without knowing how $G_1$ and $G_2$ depend on each other. You must have already assumed independece in arriving at this conclusion.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but continuity theorem and Cramer wold device does not required independence, I think.

Comment: The continuous mapping theorem requires joint convergence in distribution, which you need not have here.